# getting unicode decode error while trying to load pre-trained model using torch.load(PATH)

Tags: unicode, anaconda, pytorch

Trying to load a ResNet 18 pre-trained model using the torch.load(PATH) but getting Unicode decode error please help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 312, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 138, in main
    checkpoint = torch.load(args.resume)
  File "F:\InsSoft\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 593, in load
    return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "F:\InsSoft\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 773, in _legacy_load
    result = unpickler.load()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbe in position 2: invalid start byte
```

Comment: which python version are you using? Did you update pytorch after pre-training?

Comment: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/5994 it may help.

Comment: @WasiAhmad yes, pytorch was updated after pre training

Answer (score 2):

This error hits whenever the model is pretrained on torch version `< 0.4` but using torch version `> 0.4` for testing / resuming.
so use `checkpoint = torch.load(args.resume,encoding='latin1')`